# Fix or Replace the Handler code to auto-random

Tags: java, android, random, handler

I need help in here, so i want to use Handler to auto-Random my case list every 2 second

the full code is like this

```
public class play extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

int number;
Button button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, button11, button12, button13, button14, button15, button16;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.play);


     button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
     button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
     button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
     button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
     button6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
     button7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
     button8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
     button9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
     button10 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
     button11 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
     button12 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);
     button13 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button13);
     button14 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button14);
     button15 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button15);
     button16 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button16);

//i had use setOnClickListener(This) to make all of button do same logic in one method
// correct me if i wrong

       button1.setOnClickListener(this);
       button2.setOnClickListener(this);
       button3.setOnClickListener(this);
       button4.setOnClickListener(this);
       button5.setOnClickListener(this);
       button6.setOnClickListener(this);
       button7.setOnClickListener(this);
       button8.setOnClickListener(this);
       button9.setOnClickListener(this);
       button10.setOnClickListener(this);
       button11.setOnClickListener(this);
       button12.setOnClickListener(this);
       button13.setOnClickListener(this);
       button14.setOnClickListener(this);
       button15.setOnClickListener(this);
       button16.setOnClickListener(this);

}



// this is the method to make all of the button do same logic with one method
// correct me if i wrong

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

//i use the handler method to do auto-random every 2 second
// correct me if i wrong

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    final int ms=2000; //2secs.
//i got error in this line
// Define cannot be resolved to a type, Syntax error on token ":", { expected after this token, Syntax error, insert ";" to complete


    Define a Runnable: 

    final Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Random generator = new Random();
            number = generator.nextInt(16) + 1; 


             // The '16' is the number of values

             // Here, we are checking to see what the output of the random was
             switch(number) { 

              case 1:  
              button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 2: 
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 3:  
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 4:  
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 5:  
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 6:  
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 7:  
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 8:  
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 9:  
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 10: 
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 11: 
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 12: 
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                   
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 13: 
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 14: 
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 15: 
              button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              break;
              case 16: 
              button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button8.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button9.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button10.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button11.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button12.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);                     
              button13.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button14.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button15.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              button16.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              break;

           }


// the auto-random will be faster and faster
// correct me if i do it wrong too


            }
        };


        ms=ms-20; //20ms faster
        mHandler.postDelayed((Runnable) this, ms);
        mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100); 

}  

}
```

After i search what is the problem now i found it is true the force close cause by Handler method :

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    int ms=2000; //2secs.



    final Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        //Do random logic

               }

        };

    ms=ms-20; //20ms faster
    mHandler.postDelayed((Runnable) this, ms);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100); 

 }
}
```

i'm sorry if you're madness look at my code, because that i was need help with people more experience to fix the current problem or anyone have some sample code to replace the handler method?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Arrays and loops were made for this reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Define a Runnable:` is not valid Java. Either remove it, or comment it out.

Further, to clean up the code, do something like this:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[]{ button1, button2, ... button15,  button16 }; 
// fill in the other buttons above

Random generator = new Random();
number = generator.nextInt(16); 

for( int i=0; i<buttons.length; i++ ) {
   if( i == number )
       buttons[i].setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
   else
       buttons[i].setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
}
```

Lastly, you'll likely receive a ClassCastException when you do this:

```
mHandler.postDelayed((Runnable) this, ms);
```

`this` in that context is likely the `Activity`, which isn't a `Runnable`. Instead, just do:

```
mHandler.postDelayed( mUpdateTimeTask, ms );
```

and remove the second line. You can also post the runnable itself to the handler in the `run()` method:

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
int ms=2000;

final Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Do random logic

        ms -= 20;
        if( ms > 0 ) // stop when delay is less than 0.
            mHandler.postDelayed( this, ms );
    }

};


// run this in a method.
mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, ms); // post the first
```

Comment: This code it Worked Thank's man! but can i make that ms > 0 delay not stop random?